# What song plays during the fight between Kaneki/Sasaki with Owl in Tokyo Ghoul:re episode 6?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

In episode 6 of *Tokyo Ghoul:re*, there's a song played while Kaneki/Sasaki is fighting owl.

What song is that?

Answer (score 0):

So found the song its name is unravel Idk about the singer but below is the link for it.
https://youtu.be/KBSsrFLn6SE

Answer (score 0):

The song is "Unravel" 
From : "Tk ling tosite sigure" 
^^
See ya